# Display big image in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

If I choose the big picture such as [it is](http://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=http://www.lakeshorepreserve.wisc.edu/photo-gallery/bigwoods/lg/Big%2520Woods%2520Aerial,%2520Cronon,%2520DSC_8790.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.lakeshorepreserve.wisc.edu/visit/bigwoods.htm&h=2000&w=3008&sz=1574&tbnid=bUYyrcldF3GAxM%3a&tbnh=93&tbnw=140&zoom=1&usg=__-V3U-FJCCA-NOTpk-Tzk4psH_68=&docid=GhTYWqNlIbdBnM&sa=X&ei=gHqFUfigHcWk4gSthoGoCQ&ved=0CEIQ9QEwBA&dur=279) from Gallery and try display it in ImageView, the ImageView will not display it.

```
public class ColorViewerActivity extends Activity {

    // SKIP OTHER METHODS

    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO_REQUEST = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.open_image:
            selectImage();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

        switch(requestCode) { 
        case SELECT_PHOTO_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why?? Because the image is too big?

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that because of this. WebView can display large items, but it throws out of memory exceptions sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use huge image which exceeds your memory it will Throw

> java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

To know how to display bitmaps efficiently check [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)